# Franklin's missing ships

Tags: exploration

I know there have been recent searches for the Erebus and Terror but I can't seem to find anything up to date on any findings. Do you suppose it utterly possible with the ongoing melting of the Arctic that the greatest mystery of Arctic exploration could be solved?

Comment: The Wikipedia link you provided has a pretty complete list of modern searches, including a new one that's set to start in early August. The thing I find really interesting is that [Canada is highly motivated](http://reviewcanada.ca/magazine/2012/05/the-franklin-mystery/) to find the ships, as they may help back up their claim to the (soon to be ice-free) Northwest passage.

Comment: @T.E.D~ I agree with you about the NW passage aspect of the question...It will be interesting to see how that plays out in the 21st century. The opening of the passage, due to changing weather patterns, to easier travel and exploration/exploitation makes Barrow's incessant drive to open the passage in the 1800's seem rather prescient.

Comment: Mark C Wallace A big thank you for completely altering the style and tone of my question. Your editing skills are with out peer. It's almost like I didn't even ask this question...

Comment: ...and yes, that is sarcasm.

Comment: I had a bad day yesterday and was rude; I apologize and have deleted my comment.  That said, SE members are **expected** to edit questions.  I'm sorry that you didn't like the changes, but H:SE questions should not request opinions, and should demonstrate prior research. I believe that at least a minimal link to references is necessary when asking about events that are obscure. Can we find a way to revise your question to fit within the [site guidelines](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but preserve your style and tone?

Comment: Yes, it is utterly possible that THE greatest mystery of Arctic exploration can be solved. Oh, you're not talking about where the polar bears will migrate? Well, hell, I answered the question anyway, didn't I.

Comment: ...and yes, that **IS** sarcasm.

Answer (score 4):

Melting in the Arctic will not directly help finding the ships as they are likely sunk or [stripped by locals for their metals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Investigator_(1848)#Legacy).  Arctic resource exploration may cause them to be found simply for the greater number of people poking around with instruments up there.

[HMS Investigator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Investigator_%281848%29), a ship lost searching for Franklin, was found by Parks Canada in 2010 by sonar.  It was found 11 meters underwater and partially buried in silt.  This suggests maybe Erebus and Terror will be found, except for one key difference: the captain and crew of Investigator survived.  Parks Canada knew what had happened to her, and knew roughly where to search.

[Parks Canada Expedition](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/culture/franklin/index.aspx) mounted a search for Erebus and Terror in August 2013.  I haven't been able to find a report.

**UPDATE** [The 2014 Victoria Strait Expedition found one of them](http://www.pm.gc.ca/eng/news/2014/09/09/statement-prime-minister-canada-announcing-discovery-one-ill-fated-franklin), not sure which yet.

Comment: Knowing where to look is a huge deal. To horribly misquote Douglas Adams: "The ocean is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind- bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to the ocean."